# Marketing cloud SOAP API authentication

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to test the functionality of FuelSDK (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python) for Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

I created a Developer Account on Salesforce and logged into Marketing Cloud. In their documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/marketing-cloud/ I am following the `Step 1: Install a Package manual` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm).

I go to `Setup > Apps > Packaging > Package Manager` and click `New` there (the options from the manual are not there, but I assume they just renamed some fields). After filling the Name and the Description, however, I don't see the info about `Package ID`, `JWT Signing Secret`, and `Source Account`. Consequently, I can't add API integrations. Consequently I can't get the `ClientID` and `Client Secret` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm).

Any idea how I could make this work please?

Comment: Are you doing these steps within the Marketing cloud? The click path would be Setup > Apps > Installed Packages > New

Comment: wow this might be the case! however, I am not sure how I can actually log to the Marketing Cloud (or spin off an instance of one) as a Developer. If I navigate to here https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/, my developer credentials do not work (which I assume is because I don't have an instance of Marketing Cloud). And without one, I can't get the credentials. Thanks a lot for your help, @EazyE!

Comment: There is currently no such thing as a developer account for marketing cloud